# How to validate my Pig input data is as per the dml

Tags: apache-pig

How to validate my input data is correct as per the dml.

Input Data:
Jorge Posada |Yankees| {(Catcher,2000),(Designated_hitter,2001)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003),**(Left_fielder)**}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]

**See in the bold part ,I have missed the year field.**
bfile= LOAD 'basketball1.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:tuple(point:chararray,year:int)},bat:map[]);

dump bfile;
(Jorge Posada ,Yankees,{(Catcher,2000),(Designated_hitter,2001)},[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7])
(Landon Powell ,Oakland,{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001)},[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7])
**(Martin Prado ,Atlanta,,[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3])**

Regards
Sanjeeb

Comment: Can you add more samples to validate the input? both valid and invalid .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex script for your schema, mostly i validated all the fields. Please run against your inputs and let me know if you need other validations.

**Regex:**

```
'^
   ([A-Za-z]+\\s+[A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\|\\s*
   ([A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\|\\s*
   (\\{(?:\\([A-Za-z_]+,[0-9]+\\))(?:,\\([A-Za-z_]+,[0-9]+\\))*\\})\\s*\\|\\s*
   (\\[(?:[A-Za-z_]+#[0-9\\.]+)(?:,[A-Za-z_]+#[0-9\\.]+)*\\])
 $'
```

**input.txt**
i have marked each below input is valid or invalid

```
Jorge Posada |Yankees| {(Catcher,2000),(Designated_hitter,2001)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7] -->Valid
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7] ->Valid
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003),(Left_fielder)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3] -->Invalid year missing
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002)(Infielder,2003)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3] ->Invalid no comma between two tuples
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {,(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3] --> Invalid comma in the start of tuple
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(,2003)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]  -->Invalid position is missing
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003)}[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3] --> Invalid Demiiter | is missing
Martin Prado || {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003)}[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3] --> Invalid Team name is missing
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003)}[games#,hit_by_pitch#3] --> Invalid Key value is missing for games 
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher,2000)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297]  --> Valid
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001),(test,3000)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7,test#1.2]  -->valid
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^([A-Za-z]+\\s+[A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\|\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\|\\s*(\\{(?:\\([A-Za-z_]+,[0-9]+\\))(?:,\\([A-Za-z_]+,[0-9]+\\))*\\})\\s*\\|\\s*(\\[(?:[A-Za-z_]+#[0-9\\.]+)(?:,[A-Za-z_]+#[0-9\\.]+)*\\])$')) AS (name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:(p:chararray)},bat:map[]);;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:** If the input doesn't match with schema, it will print output as null.

```
(Jorge Posada,Yankees,{(Catcher,2000),(Designated_hitter,2001)},[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]) -->Valid
(Landon Powell,Oakland,{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001)},[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]) -->Valid
() -->Invalid,Year missing
() -->Invalid,No comma between two tuples
() -->Invalid,Comma in the start of tuple
() -->Invalid,Position is missing
() -->Invalid,Demiiter | is missing
() -->Invalid Team name is missing
() -->Invalid Key value is missing for games 
(Landon Powell,Oakland,{(Catcher,2000)},[on_base_percentage#0.297]) -->Valid
(Landon Powell,Oakland,{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001),(test,3000)},[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7,test#1.2]) -->valid
```